# Formula for partial sum of Riemann zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finite Sum of Power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/finite-sum-of-power)

Suppose $f(s,k) = \sum_{n=1}^k n^{-s}$ is the Riemann zeta function truncated at the k-th term. I read on mathoverflow that there is a formula for $f(s,k)$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers, but I can't find it on the web. Would someone happen to know it or could point to a link? I am primarily interested in the case when $s$ is a negative real number.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all so much! These are wonderful answers and links!

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps that you are thinking at the formula proposed by Woon ['A New Representation of the Riemann Zeta Function zeta(s)'](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812143v1).

Comment: Thanks for the Edit @Ali Caglayan,

Comment: See too this [answer and links](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1695494/21783)

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^k n^{-s}=H^{(s)}_k$$

where $H^{(s)}_k$ is the [generalized harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

Some identities are mentioned [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/HarmonicNumber2/27/01/), e.g.

$$H^{(s)}_k=\frac{(-1)^{-s}B_{-s+1}+B_{-s+1}(k+1)}{-s+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Presumably mathoverflow was talking about [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^p = \frac{B_{p+1}(n+1)-B_{p+1}(0)}{p+1}
$$
in terms of Bernoulli polynomials.  If $p$ is a positive integer, then the coefficients of the Bernoulli polynomials are essentially Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 1):

[Faulhaber's polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) provides the answer when $s \in \mathbb{Z}^{-}$. If $s \in \mathbb{R}^-$, a good approximation can be obtained using [Euler-Maclaurin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) which also contain the Bernoulli numbers.