# Has anyone noticed this pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition

I've been messing around a bit and I noticed a curious pattern when it comes to progressions of powers.

Let's take the progression of consecutive integers:

$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...$

Obviously it's an arithmetic progression with a common distance of 1. And obviously 1 = 1!

So what if we take the progression of the squares of the above sequence?

$1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2,6^2,7^2,.. =  1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49,...
$

we notice that the distances between the numbers are

$3,5,7,9,11,13,...$

which is an arithmetic progression with a common distance of 2. Take note that 2 = 2!

Now if we do the following for the cubes:

$1^3,2^3,3^3,4^3,5^3,6^3,7^3,...=1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343,...$

we notice that the distances between the numbers are

$7, 19, 37, 61, 91, 127,...$

At the first look there doesn't seem to be a pattern here however if we take
the distances of the distances we get:

$12, 18, 24, 30, 36,...$

which as before we notice that it is an arithmetic progression with a common distance of 6. Take note that 6 = 3!

Now let's take the progression of the numbers raised in the power of 4:

$1^4,2^4,3^4,4^4,5^4,6^4,7^4,...=1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401,...$

As before we take the distances:

$ 15, 65, 175, 369, 671, 1105,...$

then the distances of the distances:

$  50, 110, 194, 302, 434,... $

and finally the distances of the distances of the distances:

$ 60, 84, 108, 132,...$

We notice again that it's an arithmetic progression with a common distance of 24. Take note that 24 = 4!

I am not sure if this pattern has been observed but it looks promising, especially for series formulas.

Comment: Have you studied calculus? If so, you might find it interesting to look at the first derivative of $y=x$, the second derivative of $y=x^2$, the third derivative of $y=x^3$, etc.

Comment: See [this](http://mathlesstraveled.com/2012/02/16/differences-of-powers-of-consecutive-integers-part-ii/).

Comment: This mechanism, of taking "distances" between consecutive values, is useful in generic Integer-Valued Polynomials as well.  It even has its own operator, $\Delta$ for general operations.  You might consider your particular method to be $p_n(x)=x^n, \Delta[p_n](x)=p_n(x+1)-p_n(x)$.

Comment: @veritas i don't see why you feel stupid. You noticed a cool pattern and Tony told you why it was related to one you might already know. You can't immediately deduce your formula from Tony's or vice versa.

Comment: **cough** factorials?  Say, if only we could do this for arbitrary exponents to generalize the factorial.  Oh wait, we can and indeed all of this happens to be the motivation to the gamma function! $$n!=\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx$$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

If the $n$ th $\displaystyle T_n=n^r$

$\displaystyle T_{m+1}-T_m=(m+1)^r-m^r=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom mkm^k$

Observe that the difference of order $O(r-1)$

If we set $T'_m= T_{m+1}-T_m,$

$T'_{s+1}-T'_s $ will be of order $O(r-2)$ and so on

**Reference** :

Finite Difference  [I](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteDifference.html), [II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)

[Finite Sum of Power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/finite-sum-of-power)

Answer (score 2):

If you have any polynomial with rational coefficients that takes positive integers to integers, it can be written uniquely in the form
$$
f(x) = a_n{x \choose n} + \ldots + a_1 {x \choose 1} + a_0
$$
where if $x$ is not an integer we define
$$
{x \choose n} = \frac{x(x-1)\ldots(x-1+n)}{n!}
$$
(mnemonic: we are taking the formula for ${x \choose n}$ where $x$ is an integer and cancelling the part of the denominator that won't make sense when $x$ isn't.)

Note that, by considering ${x \choose n}$ itself, we see that there are polynomials with rational coefficients that take positive integers to integers but don't themselves have integer coefficients.

In fact, we can recover $a_n$ as $\Delta^n(0)$ where $\Delta f(m):= f(m+1) - f(m)$ and the $n$ means to iterate the operator $n$ times.

You have applied this construction to the polynomial $x^n$ and recovered that $a_n = n!$ in this case. You can see this without doing any computation by degree considerations.