# Finding common ratio of a geometric series from a cubic

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is asking to find the sum of a geometric series up to term n, where the first value of r is 1.
The expression is $$ \sum_{r=1}^n \ 4r^3-3r^2+r$$.
I am aware of the general formula for the sum of a geometric series, but don't know what to use as the common ratio - is there any way to figure out the common ratio from the equation?

Comment: What are you summing?

Comment: [WA answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+4r%5E3-3r%5E2%2Br%2C+r%3D1..n) about $\sum\limits_{r=1}^n 4r^3-3r^2+r$ @oscar6721

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin how would you go about showing that this is the case, apart from just putting values into the expression?

Comment: Let $f(r)=4r^3-3r^2+r$ and $F(n)=An^4+Bn^3+Cn^2+Dn+E$ and $F(n)-F(n-1)\equiv f(n)$, then equate the latter term-wise, viola.

Comment: This is NOT a geometric series by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we use the identities:

$$\begin{align}&\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i^{3} = \bigg(\frac{n(n +1)}{2}\bigg)^{2}
\\&\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i^{2} = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}
\\&\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}\end{align}$$

These can be easily proved by induction. Then, for your sum we have:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^{n}4r^{3}-3r^{2} + r&= 4\sum_{r = 1}^{n}r^{3}-3\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^{2}+\sum_{r=1}^{n}r 
\\&= n^{2}(n+1)^{2}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2}+\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}
\\&=n^{2}(n + 1)^{2}-\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1 - 1)}{2} 
\\&= n^{2}(n + 1)^{2} - n^{2}(n + 1) 
\\&= \boxed{n^{4} + n^{3}}\end{align}$$

Comment: If you are interested in how these identities are derived, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/finite-sum-of-power.